# React.js - Handle exception caused by import in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exception

I just added an import line to my App.js code that caused an exception which I can see in the dev tools console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '!'`

I've read this page which explains [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) But adding componentDidCatch() to my App component doesn't help because that will never be executed, as the exception is outside of the App component / App component scope.

It's like I want a componentDidCatch() in my index.js but that index doesn't look like a component to me.

How do I handle a js / React compilation exception gracefully when it is caused by an import statement in App.js?

Maybe I could wrap my App component in AppWrapper component that implements this componentDidCatch() stuff? (or have a InnerAppComponent component) Even if that is a potential solution, I think the question is still valid and I'm wondering if there is a conventional way to deal with this problem (exceptions at the App component level)

I have the same question about my index.js file: what's the convention for handling exceptions there?

Edit: My exception was caused by a bad path in an import statement. I'm using Visual Studio and it works well and it was simple and easy to create this app but for this specific case, the compilation error is not displayed by in my browser when I'm debugging. I can run `npm run-script build` and then I see my error clearly. Still... is that the nature of a React app then? I'm old enough to remember when javascript didn't compile. This is a personal project but I can imagine for a large project / team, it would be preferable if a compilation error in a minor / obscure component only caused an error / exception when that page was loaded / that javascript executed? Did I miss the paradigm shift and that's just not how this works anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Error boundaries are here to take care about errors caused in the runtime, not compile time.

For example if you write the following code:

```
import React, {PureComponent from 'react;
```

it means you wrote broken code and this something react has nothing to do with.

In order to prevent such mistakes, you should use prettifier or maybe some powerful IDE to do error checking.

error boundaries are here to take care about errors, like for example

```
const item = getItems()[0];

const item = getSingleItem();
```

In the code above, there is a runtime error saying that the variable has already been declared or for example if the function `getSingleItem()` throws an `Error`, error boundary will be used

Comment: What happened to the good old days when javascript didn't compile? :) My error was a bad path in an import. If I run npm build with the bad path, I see a nice "Failed to compile" message. I guess my issue is with Visual Studio or whatever is refreshing the browser when I save a file. So I'm an idiot but I think some of this creating-a-new-react-app stuff could be a little friendlier when you goof something big. Like I mistyped a route and it took me an hour to figure out why my new component / page was not loading (I've found <switch> and set up a "bad-route" route) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dudeman3000 you should use an IDE for this kind of work. I have been coding in react for 5 years now and I have never typed an import statement :) I just used library and my IDE imported it automatically :)